# What is the meaning of "I’ll be up you for the rent"?

Tags: meaning, australian-english

In this [video](https://youtu.be/CssfXJlzfVs?t=103) at 1:43, Ray (the guy on the right), says something like:

> "And if I ever hear you having your eyes lifted or something done to your chin I'll be up you for the rent too by the way."

I can perfectly understand the first part of his statement, but the second one got me confused. What does *"I'll be up you for the rent too"* mean in this context?

Attempted transcription:

> Left: "Aiii, Raymunda."
>
> Right: "I could do with a nip and tuck; she doesn't need one. She's a beautiful young woman. Stop all the nonsense."
>
> Left: "All right, I think we'll leave it there, Ray [or eh]."
>
> Right: "Prob'ly a good idear."
>
> Left: (Hisses and laughs)
>
> Right: "And if I ever hear you having your eyes lifted or something done to your chin, I'll be [up to/after] you for [the rent] too, by the way."
>
> Left: "No, I know you will be. You'll be [up me in?] for [the rent] anyway."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m a native speaker of American English, and passingly familiar with British English. I’ve never heard this expression before, and given the speakers are Australian, I conclude it’s a regionalism in Australian English.

So I checked [Macquarie Dictionary](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/features/word/search/?word=Up&search_word_type=Dictionary) (the canonical reference for Australian English), and indeed the 85th entry for *up* is:

> 85. up you (for the rent), *Colloquial* (an exclamation of insolent or abusive dismissal.)

In other words, if the first speaker gets plastic surgery, the other one will mock him mercilessly.

If it weren’t for that, I would have guessed that the logic was “if you get plastic surgery, you demonstrably have disposable income aka plenty of money, so I’m going to hit you up for rent money like a mooch friend, or come after you for rent money like a landlord with deadbeat tenants who I just saw roll into the garage with a BMW”.